# View a list of recent documents in Vim

Tags: vim, recent-documents

Is there a way to view the list of *recent documents* you've opened in Vim?

I realize I could view the cursor *jump list*, `:ju`, and then go to a cursor position in the list but this is not ideal because there will be multiple listings of the same document in the list.

Is there another command which would do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Don't use a plugin, unless you want a nice menu. From [Vim Documentation: Starting](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:oldfiles) (or `:help old`):

```
:ol[dfiles]
```

Then to open one of the listed files, use: `'0`, `'1`, `'2`, ... `'9`

---

List the files that have marks stored in the `viminfo` file.

```
:bro[wse] ol[dfiles][!]
```

List file names as with `:oldfiles`, and then prompt for a number. When the number is valid that file from the list is edited. Use `!` to abandon a modified buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I view the help for Starting this command does not exist like it does in the link you supplied. Also attempting to use this command yields the error "Not an editor command". Why is this?

Comment: Works for me. @chris You know that the bits inside the brackets are optional, right? i.e. ":bro ol" is an abbreviation of ":browse oldfiles"

Comment: To open one of the listed files, use: '0, '1, '2, ... '9.  (I had to go to another question to find that answer, so I'm posting it here.)

Comment: @Stew link to that question? Those don't seem to work for me. [UPDATE] actually it works for me with `:browse oldfiles` – sorry!

Comment: @Stew : thanks for your comment which showed me the way but with a slightly different approach. If I press ' then I get options for paging through the list only when I've paged to the bottom of the list am I prompted to asking me for a file number, then the file opens !

Comment: @Stew: I should have made it clearer that in my case the list that results from "bro ol" is more than one screens worth - I guess that's not true for everyone.

Comment: Any idea how to get ":bro ol" to display files that have been opened via Quickfix? When I open a document via quick fix, it doesn't appear in the bro ol list?

Comment: You don't have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the old file list in order to open a listed file. You can remember the number then press q to exit. Then in normal mode, press '0, '1, '2, ... to open the file. I often find pressing q to be faster than scrolling to the bottom.

Comment: @JamesLawson That must be a part of the answer!

Comment: For me, I have to run `sudo chmod a+wr ~/.viminfo` to make this work. Information on recent files are stored in `~/.viminfo`, whose permission by default is `-rw-------` in my case.

Comment: I've just added `nnoremap <Leader>h :browse oldfiles<CR>` to my vimrc

Comment: This seems cool, but the list definitely isn't complete. There are tonnes of files that I know I created recently which are missing. What's the deal?

Comment: Pressing `'` simply returns to Normal mode. How can I open a file from the list on vim 8?

Comment: @BenFarmer the oldfiles list is only updated once you have exited vim. Look at the answer below for MRU (Most Recently Used) plugin if you want options to do so from within the current session.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa literally press a number key afterwards. `'` is to reference a mark, and the numbers listed in oldfiles can be referenced as special marks. See: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_marks

Answer (score 32):

The Most Recently Used (MRU) plugin provides an easy access to a list of 
recently opened/edited files in Vim. This plugin automatically stores the 
file names as you open/edit them in Vim.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=521

Comment: That works nicely. I guess I'm surprised to learn a plugin is necessary.

Comment: The nice think about MRU rather than the built-in command, is that it allows filtering on file names, and tab completion, rather than dealing with a clunky giant list every time.

Answer (score 29):

Besides `:oldfiles`, [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) has `:History`.

Answer (score 21):

Start Vim and hit Ctrl-o-o to open previously edited file. Keep hitting o (while still pressing the Ctrl key) to cycle back through earlier files. See https://dev.to/jovica/3-little-known-but-useful-vim-tips-1pbg

Answer (score 2):

vim plugin: **minibufexpl** may help you. 
the opened file list is displayed on the top or bottom of the screen:

[image]

in vim normal mode, type **:b${bufid}** to jump to the **${bufid}_th** buffer, for example: type **:b13** to jump to the **13th** buffer, ie. ngx_mail_ssl_module.c.

besidies, you can map some convenient **bindings** in your vimrc, such as:

```
" ------------------------------- minibufexpl mappings -----------------------------------
"let g:miniBufExplSplitBelow=1
nnoremap <silent> <leader>bn :bn<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>bp :bp<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>bf :bf<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>bl :bl<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>bt :TMiniBufExplorer<cr>
```

Get the plugin from here: https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `oldfiles` there's a nice thing called [tinyMRU](https://github.com/romainl/vim-tinyMRU).

> Vim-tinyMRU's only purpose is to provide an intuitive alternative to the built-in :oldfile command. Nothing more, nothing less.

It's very simple:

https://github.com/romainl/vim-tinyMRU/blob/master/plugin/tinymru.vim

Answer (score 2):

A good plugin is https://github.com/Shougo/denite.nvim

You can call `:Denite file_old` in order to have fuzzy search on the list of old files. In particular, just hitting `Enter` will re-open the last opened file. Assigning a shortcut to this is useful:

```
nnoremap <leader>o :Denite<space>file_old<CR>
```

This saves few keystrokes compared to `:browse oldfiles`, `q`, `1`, `Enter`

Answer (score 1):

`:ol` works, but why not use fuzzy search to get the exact match quickly from a long list of file?

There's a very handy plugin, ctrlp which allows you to use `:CtrlPMRU`, and you can quickly get what you looking for.

For many many years, ctrlp is one of the first thing I would install for vim!

https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me to access recent files is to add the following to one's .gvimrc file:

```
let g:netrw_sort_by           = 'time'

let g:netrw_sort_direction    = 'r'
```

These lines get netrw to sort files by those most recently modified. Then one simply calls :e. and selects the file one wants.

This solution presupposes files are saved in one main directory so specified in .gvimrc. E.g.

```
cd ~/vim
```

Answer (score 0):

No directly the answer but related.

you can define `aliases` to open the last opened file(s) by vim:

```
alias vil='vim -c "normal! '\''0"' # open the last file
alias vil1='vim -c "normal! '\''1"'  # open the second last file ...
alias vil2='vim -c "normal! '\''2"'
```